# NGINX/Gunicorn - React + Flask (API) + Debian + SSL | API Communication Error

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, nginx, flask, ssl

Hive -

I have a Flask + React app running on Debian using Nginx and Gunicorn (which is maintained via supervisor).  When I set up my Nginx CONF file to just serve up the site over port 80, everything seemed to work fine except for a CORS error.  This only happened in Chrome, but the entire site worked fine in Safari (a known Chrome issue). After tracking down the issue and determining that the cause was the lack of an SSL certificate, I set up my Nginx CONF file to support SSL.  Now two things happen that frustrate me to no end:

1. When I go to the site, the Developer Console shows that the site is getting a Connection Refused on https://localhost:5000/.
2. When I use CURL to test the API, it works.

Both the React and Flask applications are hosted on the same server, and I even have port 5000 open to be safe (as well as SSL and standard 80).

My conf file is below, but some info that might be useful:

- All URLs are served up at the root "domain.com/" of the website.
- The Flask app has the API in a nested folder and the exposed API is of the format "domain.com/api/v1/{calls}".
- I have UI Swagger installed, but can not access it from the browser.
- The development environment works fine, but that is because I'm using the built-in Python/Flask server and running the frontend React app with NPM Start.

My code is below and I've left in place, as commented lines, other things I have tried to make this work to show the various efforts I've exerted.  In the location /api section, I previously just had the include proxy_params and the proxy_pass...all other lines were added after they didn't work in the location/section.  server_name has _ as the server_name. I also had this as the subdomain of my site and mixed & matched, but no dice.

```
server {
    root /var/www/project-app/frontend/build;
    index index.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
         # proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
         # proxy_redirect off;
         # proxy_set_header Host $host;
         # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/project-app/frontend/build/static;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/project/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/project/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


    access_log /var/log/project_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/project_access.log;

    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

}
server {
    if ($host = app.project.tld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    # server_name app.project.tld;
    server_name _;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

- Debian 11
- Latest Nginx Version from APT
- All packages are updated and installed via both PIP and NPM
- Python 3.9.2
- There are fillers in the code...such as app.project.tld...in my actual code, I have the subdomain of the actual app.  Just trying to avoid someone telling me I made a copy/paste snafu :)

Thanks!

Comment: You can check what is running on port 80. Another service other than Nginx may be listening on this port. You can also try connecting to the IP of the react application instead of the localhost.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @j4nus .  It looks like NGINX is correctly running on both 80 and 443.  And python3 is running on 127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: I also thought it might be a CORS issue.  I imported flask_cors into my main application file, wrapped the app in the CORS() function, and restarted Gunicorn.  If we assume the documentation is to be believed that the aforementioned CORS() function applies CORS globally, then I would assume that the issue is not with CORS since I am still getting the same error.